# How to prevent sorting in `choice` list of `wx.Choice`

Tags: python, sorting, wxpython

I'm using `wx` for building GUI app. I have several `Choice` controls on the frame, and all are sorted by ascending order. Here's the structure I use for creating and populating `Choice` widget.

```
MODES = ["test", "combo", "base", "november"]

# Part of class, but it's irrelevant
mode_choices = ["{: >4}".format(mode) for mode in MODES]
self.mode_choice = wx.Choice(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, mode_choices, style=wx.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT | wx.TB_VERTICAL)
self.mode_choice.SetFont(wx.Font (20, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
self.mode_choice.SetSelection(0)
```

Here's the screenshot of resulting widget, sorted.

[image]

I was going through official docs for `wx` and sniffed here a little, but couldn't find a way to prevent automatic sorting. Expected result would be list of strings in order in which they are in `mode_choices` list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wx.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT` and `wx.TB_VERTICAL` styles are not meant for use with `wx.Choice` and one of them likely has the same value of `wx.CB_SORT`.

Comment: `wx.TB_VERTICAL` has the same value as `wx.CB_SORT` i.e. 8